# Understanding Open sets in quotient topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let X be a topological space.Then if ~ is an equivalence relation,we define topology on X/~ be the strongest topology such that the projection map  P from X to X/~  is continuous i.e. O is open in X/~ if inverse image of O under P is open in X.What is the motivation for defining quotient topology like this and how will it capture idea of gluing?

Comment: The easiest way to see how it captures that idea is to work through some simple examples in detail. Note that it also captures the idea of squashing a set to a point.

Comment: What about the open sets?Why we defined like this?

Comment: To make the quotients do what they’re supposed to do. In the case of a gluing, for instance, that’s the only way to define the open sets that gives the pieces and the joined part the expected topology. If you’re not seeing this by thinking about the definition, it’s probably best seen by actually working through some simple examples.